# SELECT DATA WHERE FIELD IS NOT NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, propel

I'm trying to select the all the data from a table "users" where the "reset_code_date" is not null. 
How can I do this with propel?

Now I have this:

```
$canceledusers = UserQuery::create()->filterByResetCodeDate()->find();
```

As you can see, now I select all the fields where the reset_code_date IS NULL. But how can I select all the fields where it is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$canceledusers = UserQuery::create()->where('reset_code_date is not null')->find();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$canceledusers = UserQuery::create()
    ->filterByResetCodeDate(null, \Criteria::ISNOTNULL)
    ->find();
```